# Can we "learn" reflexes?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, human-anatomy, neurophysiology

Can we force our bodies to react to situations faster than our brain can think about them?

Some reflexes I can think of off the top of my head:

- knee jerk reflex
- retracting hand when touching a hot pan

Not sure if these are the same type of reflex, the second might be using the brain.

Can we instil into ourselves similarly fast reaction times to other stimuli?

Comment: Certainly, though "reflex" is probably not the correct technical term.  Practice fencing, for instance, or other martial arts, and you'll experience this for yourself.  Or even riding a bike.

Comment: Often called "muscle memory" in some sports or activities - using knives fast like chefs do...

Comment: @Solar Mike: Likewise playing keyboard or plucked musical instruments, or FTM typing.

Comment: @jamesqf but is muscle memory actually a reflex like the knee-jerk is, doesn't the nerve signal have to travel all the way to the brain first